# dropdownlist showing multiple names on refreshing

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(Session["email"].ToString());
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    string query = "select * from country";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    drpdown_country.Items.Add(new ListItem("---select---", "0"));
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            drpdown_country.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["country"].ToString(), dr["c_id"].ToString()));
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Whenever i run this code and refresh the page
It gets all the Countrynames show again

So i get as much times names of a single country as i refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running again on post back.

Wrap your code with:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack){
      //code here
    }
}
```